# Get mutiple multiple rows value base on array id IN CAKE PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

i want to get multiple rows value base on multiple id value and i m getting id in array.

id output array

```
pr($currentSessionData['Category']);
Array
(
    [Category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 25
        )

)
```

Below code for getting rows value but not working

```
$this->YourModelName->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                        "YourModelName.id" => array($currentSessionData['Category'])
                )
));
```

Comment: your code is pretty much correct.You need to check what query is generated by your find query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont use array() .eg array($currentSessionData['Category'])

Try this.

```
$cat_ids=array(0=>10,1=>51,2=>51,3=>6561,4=>1,5=>561);

$this->YourModelName->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                        "YourModelName.id" => cat_ids  /*dont use array() */
                )
));
```

i hope its helpful for you :)

Comment: yes u r right, could you tell me how can i remove category index in cakephp

Comment: $ar['Category']= array(0=>12,1=>13452,2=>1452,3=>12544);
    if(!empty($ar['Category']))
    {
     foreach ($ar['Category'] as $k=>$v)
     {
      $arr[]=$v;
      
     }
     
    }
    pr($arr);